# How to add row in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Do you know how I can add a new row to a `jTable`?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The `TableModel` behind the JTable handles all of the data behind the table.  In order to add and remove rows from a table, you need to use a `DefaultTableModel`

To create the table with this model:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"}));
```

To add a row:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});
```

You can also remove rows with this method.

Full details on the DefaultTableModel can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: +1 This is a good answer; however, note that the DefaultTableModel is only one of many models. However, it is the easiest to use and I would recommend sticking to it unless you have to use another.

Comment: On creating the table with your first line of code, I get an error "The constructor DefaultTableModel(Object[]) is undefined"

Comment: @ThisClark: For that DefaultTableModel constructor, you also need to add rowCount, like:
`JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"}, 20));`

Answer (score 60):

Use:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
JTable table = new JTable(model); 

// Create a couple of columns 
model.addColumn("Col1"); 
model.addColumn("Col2"); 

// Append a row 
model.addRow(new Object[]{"v1", "v2"});
```

Answer (score 12):

To add *row* to `JTable`, one of the ways is:

1) Create table using DefaultTableModel:

```
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("Code");
        model.addColumn("Name");
        model.addColumn("Quantity");
        model.addColumn("Unit Price");
        model.addColumn("Price");
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

2) To add row:

```
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) MyJTable.getModel();

    Vector row = new Vector();
    row.add("Enter data to column 1");
    row.add("Enter data to column 2");
    row.add("Enter data to column 3");
    model.addRow(row);
```

get the model with `DefaultTableModel modelName = (DefaultTableModel) JTabelName.getModel();`

Create a Vector with `Vector vectorName = new Vector();`

add so many `row.add` as comumns

add soon just add it with `modelName.addRow(Vector name);`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, first make sure you have the correct import so you can use the `addRow` function:

```
import javax.swing.table.*;
```

Assuming your jTable is already created, you can proceed and create your own add row method which will accept the parameters that you need:

```
public void yourAddRow(String str1, String str2, String str3){
  DefaultTableModel yourModel = (DefaultTableModel) yourJTable.getModel();
  yourModel.addRow(new Object[]{str1, str2, str3});
}
```