# Default Table Model doesn't show new lines

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

Hi i want to show new line in DefaultTableModel but i dont know why table doesn't show enters.
How to enable enters? If i have a string "stss\nsdd" it shows "stsssdd" but i want new line.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{{"some", "text"}, {"any", "text"},
                {"even", "more"}, {"text", "str\nings"},
                {"and", "other"}, {"text", "values"}}, new Object[]{
                "Column 1", "Column 2"});

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowHeight(40);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to add a new row then look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable

Comment: not new row. New line in cell

Comment: @Luffy It's because the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends `JLabel` which don't handle `\n`. May you try to define your own renderer :)

Comment: Is there any other Table model witch handle new lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in easy way

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>Hello World!<br>blahblahblah</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER)
```

Comment: I only use string "<html>Hello World!<br>blahblahblah</html>"
It was only example.
JLabel can interpret Html and it works except that i need to set width properly.

Comment: You mean you have the html-text as data in your model?

Comment: Yes i changed to html-text.

Comment: okay, that's possible - could be a bit inconvenient to keep all the data as html :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the DefaultTableCellRenderer uses JLabel as the component to paint the cells. And labels can't have new lines. You have to use your own TableCellRenderer that uses a TextComponent that accepts new lines, for example JTextArea.

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); // or static field
//...
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer()
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        textArea.setText(value.toString());
        return textArea;
    }

});
```

Try copying and pasting a text of a couple of lines, to see it work. Now you might want to  cahnge the cellEditor and prevent the Enter key from finalizing the edition so it can be used to write new lines in the cells.

Comment: +1 for a custom renderer, -1 for creating a new component on each call

Comment: @kleopatra true, that's why DefaultTableCellRenderer **is** also a JLabel and in its implementation sets its texts and simply returns `this`.

Comment: actuallly .. no: DTCR being-a JLabel is a design accident that shouldn't be repeated (as you correctly don't :) Not extending is no reason to not re-use the same instance of a rendering component.

Comment: ehh .. how about just doing it (vs. adding a comment)? Simply move the line out off the method and you are fine :-)

Comment: There is a lot things to change to make it works corectly in all cases. I will search for diffrent table.

Comment: out off the method doesn't mean out off the anonymous class :-)

Comment: @Luffy there's no way around learning to use a framework, be it Swing or something else :-) Good luck, anyway