# Adding rows to a model but not getting added. Getting arrayindex out of bounds exception

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am trying to create an empty table with 5 columns and adding rows to it. I have created a separate tablemodel class that extends `AbstractTableModel`.

The class is :

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
 {
    private String[] columnNames = {"Name",
                                    "Size",
                                    "Directory",
                                    "Last Modified Time",
                                    "Readable"};

    Object[][] data=new Object[][]{

    };

    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return columnNames.length;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int col) 
    {
        return columnNames[col];
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) 
    {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
    {
            if (col < 1) 
        {
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) 
    {
        data[row][col]=value;

    }
    public void updateJarTable(Object[] row)

    {
        setValueAt(row[0],0,0);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        setValueAt(row[1],0,1);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        setValueAt(row[2],0,2);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        setValueAt(row[3],0,3);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        setValueAt(row[4],0,4);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}
```

After this i am creating a table and applying this tablemodel to it as :

```
table=new JTable(new MyTableModel());
```

when i click a button, a new row should be appended.

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
Object[] row={"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"};
model1.updateJarTable(row);
table.revalidate();
}
});
```

Where model1 is :

```
private MyTableModel model1=new MyTableModel();
```

But when i run it am getting `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` at the methods : `updateJarTable` and `setValueAt`

I don't know where i have gone wrong. please help me to find it. thanks !

Comment: It's better to use DefaultTableModel rather than reinvent wheel implementing your own table model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment and have a look at your code...

First you do...

```
table=new JTable(new MyTableModel());
```

Then you do...

```
model1.updateJarTable(row);
```

How is `model1` related to the model you assigned to the table?

Try using...

```
table=new JTable(model1);
```

instead, just make sure that `model1` is initialised BEFORE you apply it to the table and that you don't reassign it later (doing something like `model1 = MyTableModel()` again...

The `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` is down to the fact that you have an empty array

```
Object[][] data=new Object[][]{};
```

`0` rows, `0` columns.

You either need to recreate the array to accomidate the new data, which isn't all that easy or use a more dynamic data structure, like `java.util.List` or simple use a `DefaultListModel` which does this.

**Updated with List based model**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Name",
        "Size",
        "Directory",
        "Last Modified Time",
        "Readable"};

    List<List> rows;

    public MyTableModel() {
        rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        // Don't do this, what happens if the cell value is null??
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col < 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        List columns = rows.get(row);
        columns.set(col, value);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void updateJarTable(Object[] row) {
        List columns = new ArrayList(row.length);
        columns.addAll(Arrays.asList(row));
        rows.add(columns);
        fireTableRowsInserted(rows.size() - 1, rows.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        List columns = rows.get(rowIndex);
        return columns.get(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Or you could just do...

```
String[] columnNames = {"Name",
    "Size",
    "Directory",
    "Last Modified Time",
    "Readable"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
//...
Object[] row={"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"};
model.addRow(row);
```

And save yourself the trouble...

Comment: Ya great find. i changed it and tried. again i am getting the same exception !!

Comment: I am new to java and havn't used List or Vector. Can you please tell me how do i replace the lines at "SetValueAt" and "GetValueAt" methods if i use list or vector ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems your problem in next lines:

```
Object[][] data=new Object[][]{

};
```

You have array `Object[0][]` because you can't set value to that and catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

1) You can specify dimension of your array.

2) Or store data in `List` for example.

3) Programatically extend array, if that need, when you set values.

Also try [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).

Comment: If i use a List instead of 2D array, how do i change the line in "SetValueAt" and "GetValueAt" methods ?

Answer (score 1):

I have already posted an answer in the same context.

Please find it here [how to add an array to a Jtable when button is clicked java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590120/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-jtable-when-button-is-clicked-java/22590795#22590795).

Use `DefaultTableModel` and simple call `addRow()` method on it to add a new row.

Comment: @braj Even i have tried this before getting into creating a new class. But that addRow() method didn't work. My table was not updating. Don't know why !

Comment: Please have a look on the sample code posted at mentioned link.

Comment: @Braj yeah actually i was seeing exactly that post yesterday when i started with this. Tried to implement it. But didn't work. So moved on to this method !

Comment: Where are you facing problem? Are you getting any exception? or something else. Please provide some info.