# how to list an items to a JTable

Tags: java, sql, jtable

I am trying to create a checkout simulation for my coursework. So every time I search for an item I can retrieve it from the database and display it on the JTable. However, once I add an item to the list and try to add another item the old item get replaced by the new item.

I am trying to list all the item in the JTable, this is my code:

```
DBConnection db = new  DBConnection();
    try {

        ResultSet rs =  DBConnection.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, MESSAGE FROM STOCK WHERE ID = '"+ id + "'"); 

        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));




    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }`
```

Comment: What list?  What table? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Don't use `DbUtils`, it's not doing you any favours.  Instead, build a `TableModel`, which remain constant and add the new rows to from the `ResultSet`.  See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)`, which is creating a brand new `TableModel`, filled with the contents of the `ResultSet`, this, when applied to the `JTable` is replacing the view with the contents of the `TableModel`.

In order to be able to update the table, you need to update the existing `TableModel`...

There are a few ways this might be achieved, by the simplest might be to use a `DefaultTableModel`...

Start by creating a class instance field of a `DefaultTableModel`...

```
public class ... {
    //...
    private DefaultTableModel stockTableModel;
    //...
```

Then, when you want to load the stock items, you will need to initialise the model, if it's not already initialised, and then add the new results to it...

```
DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
try (ResultSet rs = DBConnection.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, MESSAGE FROM STOCK WHERE ID = '" + id + "'")) {

    if (stockTableModel == null) {
        stockTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        for (int col = 0; col < metaData.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            stockTableModel.addColumn(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
        }
        jTable.setModel(model);
    }

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector rowData = new Vector(metaData.getColumnCount());
        for (int col = 0; col < metaData.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            rowData.add(rs.getObject(col + 1));
        }
        stockTableModel.addRow(rowData);
    }

} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom data model that allows you to insert new rows to table.

lets say that you have class, that can hold your query result fields.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    private Long id;
    private String message;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String value) {
        this.message= value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return id.compareTo(o.id);
    }

}
```

and it needs to go to table, which has been defined somewhere like:

```
JTable table =new JTable();
```

this is a data model to your table

```
public class Model extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Item> items;

    public Model() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex > items.size() - 1 || rowIndex < 0) {
            return "";
        }
        final Item get = items.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return get.getId();
            case 1:
                return get.getMessage();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "id";
            case 1:
                return "message";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void addItem(Item i) {
        items.add(i);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setId(rs.getLong("ID"));
            item.setMessage(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            items.add(item);
            fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

now create field

```
Model myModel=new Model();
```

and set it as a table model

```
table.setModel(myModel);
```

now every time you need to add something to table, just use our table model (i created two methods to insert data `public void addItem(Item i)` and `public void addItem(ResultSet rs)`.

this should work. If you need to clear table sometimes, just add pubic method `public void clear()` to your model, in which you will clear items list and call `fireTableDataChanged();`. It is necessary, otherwise GUI will not refresh.

**EDIT**

Your code should be like

```
    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
    try {

        ResultSet rs = DBConnection.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, MESSAGE FROM STOCK WHERE ID = '" + id + "'");

        myModel.add(rs);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

Comment: *"You have to create a custom data model "* - No you don't, you could use a `DefaultTableModel` - also your last example snippet doesn't meet up with your `TableModel` contract

Comment: @MadProgrammer well as it is just example, i didnt bother to work completely assuming, that intentions are clear. `DefaultTableModel` is also solution, but in my opinion custom model is much better. `DefaultTableModel` i consider as a fast prototype solution. But i will make adjustments, so it will be more suitable answer

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I normally prefer to start with `AbstractTableModel`...just saying it's not a *"have to"* situation and given the OPs apparent lack of knowledge, might be a little over there head...but what better time to learn to swing, then while you're drowning ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a row to your JTable Model every time you have your result...

refer to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable)

```
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});
```

or in your case

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            model.addRow(new Object[]{searchResultData});
```

Comment: its a specific, what i am  trying to do is get the data from the database and add it to the JTable List but at the moment every time i search for an item from a text field it gets added to the JTable. however when i try to add another item to the JTable list it replaces the old one and shows the new one. but i want both of the items to be listed to the JTable.

Comment: how to display multiple data to a JTable instead of only one . if you look at my code you can see that i am using WHERE clause  in my SQL statement. so every time i  try to add a product it adds but it gets replaced when i try to add another one.

Comment: i have tried it already and keep getting this result in to one of the field of the table "org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet42@7b06a956"

Comment: don't just put your resultSet in the table directly...try rs.getString("id") or something depending on your table specs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys I have managed to sort it out