# Having trouble with Java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need help making a program where I make functions then in Main I output all the values into a table. The function are values of the Volume of a sphere, cone, and rectangle. The problem im having is all the examples ive seen on the internet are all where you already declare whats in the table like this

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

    String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};

    Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };
```

Comment: so you want to add rows ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable

Comment: No I want to have it output the values I compute not have them pre assigned like in the example

Comment: table column names or cell values ?

Comment: Im trying to get cell values

Comment: create a table .then compute.then append rows .or calculate then make the table

Comment: would you happen to have an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable