# Add values to existing JTable dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've created a JTable using following way. This table has 5 columns and 4 rows.
All 4 rows are empty in this status.

```
String[] columns = {"Emplotee ID","Name","Address","City","Salary"};

//Table that already have 4 empty rows
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns,4); 
JTable detail = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(detail);
```

Now I want to add values into those empty rows using String array.
The GUI of this program has 5 JTextFields to get user input. When I enter values into JTextFileds and click Add button, all JTextFiled values get by String array named values.

```
String[] values = new String[6];
//When click addButton all textFiled data should go into table
addButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
        values[0] = idField.getText(); //get JTextFields data into array 
        values[1] = nameField.getText();
        values[2] = addressField.getText();
        values[3] = cityField.getText();
        values[4] = salaryField.getText();

        //What now?
    }
});
```

I know I can use this to add new row into the table. But this is not the feature what I want.

```
DefaultTableModel newModel = (DefaultTableModel)detail.getModel();
newModel.addRow(values);
```

Comment: Have you seen this link? It should be an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable

Comment: This is not what I want. I already have a JTable with 4 empty rows. I don't want to add another rows to it and just need to add values to existing rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set contents of an existing table row with:

```
int row;
....
// make sure row is set to index of the table row
// you want to populate
for (int c=0; c<values.length; ++c)
    detail.setValueAt(values[c], row, c);
```

`TableModel` also has `setValueAt` method, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks dude. I tried to look a built in method for doing above task. But this is also working for me.