# How to make scroll pane appear after dynamically adding text fields to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a program, where text fields are being added dynamically to a JPanel, but when too many fields are added, I want a scrollbar to be shown, so that the user doesn't have to resize the window in order to see all the fields. So far I can generate the fields without a problem, but adding the scrollbar seems not to be working...
I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class AddRuleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel panel;
JPanel buttonPanel;
JScrollPane scroll;
private JButton btnAddType;
private JButton btnDeleteField;
private JButton btnSaveRule;

public AddRuleFrame() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
    this.buttonPanel=new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    //Initializing the JScrollPane
    scroll = new JScrollPane(this.panel);
    scroll.setViewportView(this.panel);


    btnAddType = new JButton("Add type");
    btnAddType.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(btnAddType);

    btnDeleteField = new JButton("Delete field");
    btnDeleteField.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(btnDeleteField);

    btnSaveRule = new JButton("Save rule");
    buttonPanel.add(btnSaveRule);
    this.panel = new JPanel();     
    this.panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(538, 487);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getSource()==this.btnAddType){
        this.panel.add(new JTextField(20));
        this.panel.revalidate();
    }
    if(evt.getSource()==this.btnDeleteField){
        System.out.println("delete pressed");
    }
    if(evt.getSource()==this.btnSaveRule){
        System.out.println("");
    }

    validate();
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddRuleFrame frame = new AddRuleFrame();
}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the scroll pane simply was that you were adding it to nothing and setting its viewport before the panel was intialized.

However, I noticed a few other issues.

One issue is that `FlowLayout` adds components horizontally, so I've changed the layout of the panel to a [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and created a small subclass of `JTextField` to override the maximum size. (`BoxLayout` uses maximum sizes to size components, so without doing that the text fields get stretched to the height of the panel.)

I also used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to start the program on the Swing thread, as show in the [*Initial Threads*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) tutorial.

Instead of calling `setSize` on a `JFrame` directly, I overrode `getPreferredSize` and calculated a size dynamically based on the screen dimensions, then called `pack()` to size the components automatically. In general, Swing isn't designed for explicitly setting pixel dimensions.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class AddRuleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JButton btnAddType;
    private JButton btnDeleteField;
    private JButton btnSaveRule;

    public AddRuleFrame() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        btnAddType = new JButton("Add type");
        btnAddType.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(btnAddType);

        btnDeleteField = new JButton("Delete field");
        btnDeleteField.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(btnDeleteField);

        btnSaveRule = new JButton("Save rule");
        buttonPanel.add(btnSaveRule);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        scroll = new JScrollPane(panel,
                                 JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                 JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // this centers the window
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == btnAddType) {
            panel.add(new BoxyTextField(20));
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        validate();
    }

    class BoxyTextField extends JTextField {
        BoxyTextField(int width) {
            super(width);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getMaximumSize();
            size.height = getPreferredSize().height;
            return size;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // See my exchange with MadProgrammer in the comments for
        // a discussion of whether Toolkit#getScreenSize() is an
        // appropriate way to get the screen dimensions for sizing
        // a window.
//        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        // This is the correct way, as suggested in the documentation
        // for java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds():
        GraphicsConfiguration config = getGraphicsConfiguration();
        Insets  insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config);
        Dimension size = config.getBounds().getSize();
        size.width  -= insets.left + insets.right;
        size.height -= insets.top  + insets.bottom;
        // Now we have the actual available space of the screen
        // so we can compute a relative size for the JFrame.
        size.width   = size.width / 3;
        size.height  = size.height * 2 / 3;
        return size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AddRuleFrame frame = new AddRuleFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

For your comment, generally the correct way to add a gap between components with a `BoxLayout` is to use a filler component. This is discussed in the tutorial, which I already linked to.

So you might do something like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == btnAddType) {
        if (panel.getComponentCount() > 0) {
            panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        }
        panel.add(new BoxyTextField(20));
        panel.revalidate();
    }
```

However, this creates a bit of an issue if you're planning on removing stuff dynamically, because you need to remember to remove the filler component as well:

```
    if (evt.getSource() == btnDeleteField) {
        int lastZIndex = panel.getComponentCount() - 1;
        if (lastZIndex >= 0) {
            panel.remove(lastZIndex);
            if (lastZIndex > 0) {
                panel.remove(lastZIndex - 1);
            }
            panel.revalidate();
        }
    }
    validate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

So I think the best option is that instead of extending `JTextField` and adding the the text field and filler to the panel directly, extend `JPanel`, and do something like this:

```
class BoxyTextFieldCell extends JPanel {
    JTextField jTextField;

    BoxyTextFieldCell(int width, int margin) {
        jTextField = new JTextField(width);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(jTextField);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(margin));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension size = super.getMaximumSize();
        size.height = getPreferredSize().height;
        return size;
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == btnAddType) {
        panel.add(new BoxyTextFieldCell(20, 10));
        panel.revalidate();
    }
    if (evt.getSource() == btnDeleteField) {
        int lastZIndex = panel.getComponentCount() - 1;
        if (lastZIndex >= 0) {
            panel.remove(lastZIndex);
            panel.revalidate();
        }
    }
    validate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

Doing something like that certainly leaves you with a lot of flexibility.

Otherwise, I think you could also use an editable [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with a single column (which more or less behaves just like a stack of text fields) and use `setRowMargin(int)`. I guess it might end up being easier to use a `JTable` if you aren't very comfortable with using layouts yet. See [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3549206/2891664) for examples of adding and removing rows in a `JTable`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works perfect! I just have one more question: 
How can I set the "vertical gap" between the text fields?

Comment: See my edit for some suggestions for that. You might also find that using a `JTable` is easier, which is something I didn't think of when originally writing my answer.

Comment: *"I overrode getPreferredSize and calculated a size dynamically based on the screen dimensions"* - Then `Toolkit#getScreenSize` isn't the best choice for the tasks, as it doesn't take into account the "viewable" area (ie the space excluding things like the taskbar/dock). It might be better to use the `Scrollable` interface and define the result for `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` which affect the `JScrollPane`'s `preferredSize`

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's true. Actually I think the best way to do what I intended is as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getMaximumWindowBounds--) by using `jFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()` and then subtracting `Toolkit.getScreenInsets(...)`. It's kind of inconvenient to explain in a simple answer, though. Usually I just ignore the issue altogether.

Comment: @Radiodef Up until we get another question about why the window doesn't look "centered" or appears beneath those widgets :P - There's also `getScreenInsets` from `Toolkit` ;)

Comment: The delete event didn't work as expected,but I edited it:

           if (evt.getSource() == btnDeleteField) {
             int comps = panel.getComponentCount();
             if (comps == 1) {
                 panel.remove(comps-1);
                 panel.revalidate();
             }
             if(comps>1){
              panel.remove(comps-1);
              panel.remove(comps-2);
              panel.revalidate();
             }
         }
          validate();
         panel.repaint();

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems :

1) You never add your `JScrollPane` to anything.

2) You set its viewport view to a `Component` that is `null` (not yet initialized).

This is a modified version of your constructor that fixes both problems (see comments in the code) :

```
public AddRuleFrame() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    //Initializing the JScrollPane

    btnAddType = new JButton("Add type");
    btnAddType.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(btnAddType);

    btnDeleteField = new JButton("Delete field");
    btnDeleteField.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(btnDeleteField);

    btnSaveRule = new JButton("Save rule");
    buttonPanel.add(btnSaveRule);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scroll.setViewportView(panel);// Set the viewport view only when the panel has been initialized 
    getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);// Add the scrollpane, not the panel

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(538, 487);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the scroll direction. If you now add the TextFields they are added horizontally.

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier : Sure, if there is an horizontal scrolling, there is no "max" width of the panel, so everything gets added "on the same line" by the `FlowLayout`. However, this behavior can change if the layout manager is different (e.g `panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`).