# how to add new row to jtable in jframe in netbeans8.0.2?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

**when key relese from the red marked area add new row.**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fjoH.jpg]

Comment: Please provide relevant code releated to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add row in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable)

Answer (score 1):

First of all use a proper image description...

To your question: You can see the answer in your picture. You just have to edit the tablemodel (right side at the bottom). There you can insert a new row or a new column and put some test data into the table.

If you want to learn swing I wouldn't recommend to start with the GUI designer. Yes it's a very useful tool and probably the best GUI designer for Java atm but the downside is that you don´t learn the basics of swing with that.

I would recommend to create some JFrames first via coding them by yourself and by recreating some good examples like this one: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jframe/java-jframe-example/
or this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html