# Sorting array of different data types

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of objects that each consists of a string, double and integer for each object in the array. I'd like to know how it is possible to sort this array by the first value (string) alphabetically.

I tried `Arrays.sort(data)` but I receive an error as I think it stops when it reaches the double.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
>       at java.lang.Double.compareTo(Double.java:49)

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Database.getStockArray().size(); i++) {

        String item = Database.getStockArray().get(i).getItem();
        double price = Database.getStockArray().get(i).getPrice();
        int quantity = Database.getStockArray().get(i).getQuantity();


        Object[] data = {item, price, quantity};

        model.addRow(data);
}
```

Comment: You have to cast the double value into String first.

Comment: how do you want to sort strings and doubles/integers? there is no logical way at all to sort them

Comment: You don't have "an array of objects that each consists of a string, double and integer for each object in the array", you have "an array that consists of a string, double and integer".

Comment: Not only is there no logical way to sort them, there is no logical *reason* to sort them. What does it mean to present the array as `{quantity, item, price}` rather than `{item, price, quantity}`? These three items have specific semantic meanings; to sort them arbitrarily seems meaningless.

Comment: while capturing data - capture in  treemap with item as key and value in a map with price and quantity as key and value,
Treemap<item,hashmap<price,quantity>>

Comment: You need to define the comparator to use the first cell of each `Object[] data` to sort the array.

Comment: What is the collections you are using ? `model` ? based on that type, the sort can be done in different ways

Comment: Looks like it is derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3549341/7109162)

Comment: Voted to reopen since the real problem OP is having is not knowing **what** to exactly sort and **where** should the sort happen.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `double` and `int` to `String`, for example

```
String p = Double.toString(price);
String q = Integer.toString(quantity);
```

and then you can sort all values as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing together two different things:

1. Your three-membered array of item, price and quantity is actually a record (struct, object) and should be implemented as class. It's nonsense to sort record members.
2. You can then sort collection or array of such class' instances using `Comparator.comparing(Data::getItem)` (assuming you name your class `Data`). If you really want to represent your record as array, which I consider ugly, use `Comparator.comparing((Data data) -> data[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know how it is possible to sort this array by the first value (string) alphabetically.

You need to define a comparator to sort your specific object array using the first cell, cast it into a String an simply compare with those value. (You might need to manage `null` if this can happen!

```
    new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
            String s1 = (String) o1[0];
            String s2 = (String) o2[0];
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    };
```

This can be validate with :

```
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Object[] { "b", 5 });
    list.add(new Object[] { "a", 42 });
    list.add(new Object[] { "c", 12 });

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
            String s1 = (String) o1[0];
            String s2 = (String) o2[0];
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    });

    //To print each array in the order
    list.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

> [a, 42]
>
> [b, 5]
>
> [c, 12]

Comment: He isn't using a `List<Object[]>`. Yet it would be the way to go if he would use it

Comment: You are right @XtremeBaumer, I didn't notice it was `model.addRow`, a `TableModel` maybe ? The comparator remain correct, the way to use it ... not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I will make the following assumptions:

You have an list of objects which somehow look this:

```
class StockItem {
    private final String item;
    private final double price;
    private final int quantity;

    StockItem(String item, double price, int quantity) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

And you are trying to put them into a [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

What you need to do is to first sort the elements in the list, then you can iterate over it making an `Object[]` for each item and adding it to the model:

```
List<StockItem> stockArray = Arrays.asList(
    new StockItem("foo", 7.99, 47),
    new StockItem("bar", 4.59, 12),
    new StockItem("baz", 0.98, 1057)); // Database.getStockArray();

// 1.
Collections.sort(stockArray, Comparator.comparing(StockItem::getItem));    

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

// 2.
for (StockItem e : stockArray) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] {
         e.getItem(), e.getPrice(), e.getQuantity()
    });
}
```

Or if you prefer using streams:

```
stockArray.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(StockItem::getItem))
    .map(e -> new Object[] {e.getItem(), e.getPrice(), e.getQuantity()})
    .forEach(model::addRow);
```

Answer (score -2):

If u want to sort based on object property, The proper way is do it by Comparator interface and Collections.sort().